# Qunit Javascript unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, reference, lazy-loading, sample, qunit

I am looking for a reference on how to write unit test cases for unobstrusive javascript client validation using Qunit framework:

```
   jQuery.validator.addMethod('requiredifnotempty',
   function(value, element, parameters) {
   var otherPropertyId = '#' + parameters['otherproperty'];

// get the actual value of the other control
var otherControl = $(otherPropertyId);
var controlType = otherControl.prop('type');
var otherValue = otherControl.val();

if (controlType === 'checkbox') {
    otherValue = otherControl.prop("checked").toString();
}

if (otherValue.trim().length > 0) {
    return $.validator.methods.required.call(this, value, element, parameters);
}

return true;
}

 );
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
'requiredifnotempty',
 ['otherproperty'],
 function (options) {
    options.rules['requiredifnotempty'] = {
    otherproperty: options.params['otherproperty']
  };
   options.messages['requiredifnotempty'] = options.message;        
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are a few references:

- [QUnit self-tests](https://github.com/jquery/qunit/blob/master/test/test.js)
- [forms.js](https://code.google.com/p/js-forms/source/browse/trunk/tests/forms.js?r=145)
- [ExampleTest.html](https://github.com/coreysnyder04/Unit-Testing-with-QUnit/blob/master/tests/ExampleTest.html)
- [backbone-example](https://github.com/sixohsix/backbone-example/tree/master/tests)